# Launching Fragment B from Activity based on data collected from Fragment A with less boilerplate code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface

I have the following setup:

1. I have an `Activity` that launches a `FragmentA`.
   `FragmentA` contains a `recyclerView` and an `adapter`.
2. I have an `interfaceA` in the adapter which is implemented in `FragmentA` so that I get notified which position was clicked.
3. I have a second `interfaceB` that I created in the `FragmentA`, which is implemented in the `Activity` that launched `FragmentA` in step 1.
4. Finally, I'm launching `FragmentB` from the `Activity` based on data I get from `interfaceB`.

**Everything is working fine**, however the flow is tedious, and demands a lot of boilerplate code.

**THE GOAL** is to have the `activity` launch `fragmentB` that contains data from a single clicked item from the recyclerView within `FragmentA`.

**Question**: Can it be achieved differently?

**Code Below:**

`Activity` launches FragmentA:

```
Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentA.class.getName());
    if (fragment == null) {

        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentA.class.getName());
    }
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction
            .replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, fragment, FragmentA.class.getName())
            .addToBackStack(FragmentA.class.getName())
            .commit();
```

Inside `FragmentA` we have `recyclerView`, and `interfaceA` implemented in the `adapter`:

Adapter Class:

```
        public class AdapterA extends RecyclerView.Adapter< AdapterA.ViewHolderA> {
        
        //instances
        private Context context;
        private List<Data> dataList;
        private OnItemClickListener onItemListClickListener;
        
        //Constructor
        public AdapterA (Context context, List<Data> dataList, OnItemClickListener onItemListClickListener {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.onItemListClickListener = onItemListClickListener;
    }

onCreateViewHolder....
onBindViewHolder....
getItemCount...

class ViewHolderA RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
//instances..
//Constructor...

}
        }
```

`interface` class interfaceA:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

`interface` class interfaceB:

```
public interface SingleItemEventListener {
    void onSingleItemClicked(int position);
}
```

`FragmentA` class:

```
//Instances
private AdapterA adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private onSingleItemClicked singleItemEventListener;

onAttach...
onCreateView...

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //Setting adapter
    onSetAdapter();
}

private void onSetAdapter() {
    List<Data> dataList;

    dataList = getData();

    adapter = new AdapterA(context, dataList, new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            singleItemEventListener.onSingleItemClicked(position);
        }
    });
```

In the `Activity`, we are implementing `onSingleItemClicked` callback to receive the event and launch `FragmentB` with data received from the interface callback:

```
ActivityA implements SingleItemEventListener {
@Override
    public void onSingleItemClicked(int position) {
Data data = getData(position);

if (data != null) {
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("single_data_key", data);
Fragment fragmentB = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentB.class.getName());

        if (fragmentB == null && bundle != null) {
            fragmentB = Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentB.class.getName(), bundle);
        }

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction
                .replace(R.id.FragmentLayout, fragmentB, FragmentB.class.getName())
                .addToBackStack(FragmentB.class.getName())
                .commit();
}
}
}
```

Comment: This might be tough without seeing code, it is hard to visualize.

Comment: @Airhead shared the code.

Comment: Hmm... I'm actually not sure, no easy solution comes to mind. I'm interested to see what others come up with, I might learn something.

Comment: I mean, you could cut out 75% of the boilerplate code by just using kotlin (seriously, kotlin + android = have fun as a developer again), but that's obviously not always a viable solution. The nice thing about kotlin though, is that there are automated conversion tools in android studio, and you can intermix with Java. But of course, asking someone to change their language is not a very good answer.

Comment: Why don't you consider launching the `Fragment` directly from your adapter? Do you have any special reason for that?

Comment: @ReazMurshed my main purpose is communication and I believe that if we would like to achieve that just between fragment while keeping the activity out of it, we will have to introduce an external library like BusEvent, or using ViewModel and LiveData as mentioned by TpoM6oH

Comment: In my opinion Kotlin is not a good solution. Much of the code it generates is static messes abused as a shortcut (like reflection), for lazy developers to avoid good SOLID software practices. It's Google lowering the bar on quality again for the sake of getting more developers, but for some reason people evangelize it on every question, like religious zealots. In some way I wish our store was a bit stricter like Apple's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to your activity and use it to communicate between all you components, activity and both fragments.

You can get access to the activity's ViewModel from your fragment

```
MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) for communication, post an action to it from your fragment and listen to it in your activity to start another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same task using only single interface rather than two or you can share view models between fragments and activity.

> Method 1 : Using single interface

Define Interface as

```
public interface FragmentCallbackListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Let your Activity implement it :

```
ActivityA extend Activity implements FragmentCallbackListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
       .... 
    }
}
```

Fragments which are attached to activity implementing FragmentCallbackListener should override onAttach() of fragment as:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private FragmentCallbackListener mListener;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the listener. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mListener = (FragmentCallbackListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement FragmentCallbackListener");
        }
    }
 }
```

Pass same listener instance to Adapter :

```
adapter = new AdapterA(context, dataList, mListener);
```

> Method 2 : Using shared view model

Define view model as :

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Data> selected = new MutableLiveData<Data>();

    public void select(Data data) {
        selected.setValue(data);
    }

    public LiveData<Data> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

Inside FragmentA

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        ...
        adapter = new AdapterA(context, datalist, model);
    }
}
```

Inside adapter's view onClickListener :

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            model.select(view.getTag()); //or use getData(position) to return selected data
        }
    });
```

Inside ActivityA

```
ActivityA extend Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, data -> {
        // launch the new fragment B with selected data
        });
    }
}
```

For more details, read https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 0):

Without an external library, have you considered using a broadcast?

It still requires boilerplate, but depending on your opinion can be a bit cleaner (the activity wont need to to be an instance of any interface, you don't need any 'god object' models)

In FragmentA's adapter, when an item is clicked you send a broadcast with an explicit action and the arguments as extras. In the activity you register (and unregister) a broadcast receiver (no need to alter manifest). Finally the receiver starts FragmentB as usual.

**Fragment A / Adapter**

```
Intent item = new Intent(MY_CONSTANT);
item.putExtra(MY_EXTRA_CONSTANT, position);
getActivity().sentBroadcast(intent);
```

**Activity**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int position = intent.getIntExtra(MY_EXTRA_CONSTANT, -1);
        //TODO: Move your FragmentB transaction here
    }
};

void onPause() {
   unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}

void onResume() {
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   intentFilter.addAction(MY_CONSTANT);
   registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

Comment: We still need to pass in the position with the help of putExtra within our intent, before broadcasting it just like In my question, I'm passing the position as a parameter to retrieve the needed item from List<Object>. I like how it's another workable alternative, but it does have the boilerplate of registering/unregistering the broadcast within the activity.

Comment: Yes it doesn't eliminate boilerplate, just reduces it. There is one more solution, but uglier from my perspective - child fragments. This also gives an advantage if fragment B is always the same fragment class only with arguments changed - you would be able to communicate directly (or even get a result via setTargetFragment)

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it **without using** `Interface, BroadcastReceiver` and `ViewModel`.
Check below code:

**ActivityA.java**

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityTestBinding mBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_test);

        pushFragment(new FragmentA());
    }

    /**
     * @param fragment pass fragment you want to replace
     */
    public void pushFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
//        if fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, backStateName);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() <= 1) {
                finish();
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Here `pushFragment` method is generalized for all fragment.
And in `onBackPressed()` it will check BackStackEntryCount. If there is 1 or less count that means only last fragment is in backstack and `finish();` will be called and exit application. If there is >1 count in BackStackEntryCount then it will pop last fragment.

In your **AdapterA.java**:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (context instanceof ActivityA) {
                        FragmentB mFragmentB = new FragmentB();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelable("single_data_key", dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                        mFragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
                        ((ActivityA) context).pushFragment(mFragmentB);
                    } 
                }
            });
```

Here you already passing `context` of ActivityA. So you can check that `if (context instanceof ActivityA)` then you can call `pushFragment` method of ActivityA by using Type Casting.

So this is less boilerplate code you can integrate in your Android Project.

Comment: @Red M This code is tested and working fine. Try it once. Don't know why somebody downvote it.

Comment: From the question: "FragmentA contains a recyclerView and an adapter." Also, fragmentB receives data collected from FragmentA.

Comment: @Red M where are you facing the problem? Can you please elaborate more so I can explain you.